# Django enforce that the value of OneToOneField belongs to a ForiegnKey related object set

Tags: python, django

I have models similar to what is below:

```
class Submission(models.Model):
    round = models.ForeignKey('Round',related_name='submissions')
    text = models.TextField()

class Round(models.Model):
    favorite = models.OneToOneField('Submission',related_name='round_favorite+',null=True)
```

Is there any built-in way to enforce that Round.favorite be in Round.submissions? ie:

```
assert(favorite in round.submissions.all())
```

If not, what is the best way to enforce this assertion? The pre_save signal? Overriding Model.save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the save of the `Round` model to ensure that the `favorite` submission exists and if not save it.

If you try to save the `Round` model when the `favorite` doesn't exist ins `Submission`, there will be an exception thrown, most likely `Submission.DoesNotExist`. So you can use the exception to save and try again.